# Javascript Realtime Data Refresh - Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to have a price update in near realtime on my Wordpress site using Javascript. The script works fine when run on XAMPP, but as soon as I put it into Wordpress it doesn't load anything and just outputs... blank. A Javascript button pop up works fine so I know Javascript is working, just not my code.

The script I'm using is as follows:

```
//create the div
<div id="price"></div>

//include jQuery
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

//the function
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
refresh();
$('#price').load('realtime/price-realtime.php');
});

function refresh() {

setTimeout( function() {
$('#price').fadeOut('slow').load('realtime/price-realtime.php').fadeIn('slow');
refresh();

}, 1000);
}
</script>
```

When visiting realtime/price-realtime.php, the price updates every 1000 milliseconds as is should, fading in and out. For the sake of this example, let's just say the entire contents of price-realtime.php is simply:

```
2.00
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to include the price (a PHP output) on a webpage that doesn't need refreshing. If there's another way or better way of doing it I'd be more than happy to change my method. Hope this makes sense.

Thanks for your help..

Comment: Exactly where do you put this code in the WordPress?

Comment: Can you paste your PHP code?

Comment: @WisdmLabs I've kind of solved this now. I had to find a very awkward work around as I couldn't get popular methods to work. I have a kak-handed hook in functions.php that references a .js file containing the above script. Are you having similar issues?